# Difference between an 8-bit number in little-endian and an 8-bit number in big-endian

Tags: byte, bit, endianness

What is the difference between an 8-bit number in little-endian and an 8-bit number in big-endian on Intel 64 systems?

Comment: [Endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) is how *multi-byte* types are stored. A single byte can not have an endianness.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no difference. A sequence of only one byte looks the same when read from left to right or right to left.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. On the story behind this question: A professor at my university asked me what would happen if I posted this trick question in Stackoverflow. The result is accordingly very good and totally correct.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to mention that loading a single byte into a larger register, might apply the endianess to the register:

With little endianess the byte would maintain its numeric value.
With big endianess in a 4 byte register it would be shifted << 24.

Though I know of no such instruction, being not familiar with intel.